# Model selection for multinomial logistic regression in Stata

Tags: model-selection, stata, multinomial-logit

I have a dataset with a dependent categorical variable N = {1,2,3}, and five independent continuous variables. I am running multinomial logistic regressions for all independent variables together and alone, but I also want to find an optimal model (similar to minimum AIC). However, I appear to be unable to find a way perform model selection in Stata which is compatible with multinomial logistic regression. Is there any way to do this in Stata?